# How to access data from FutureBuilder QuerySnapshot when Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

So, I'm trying to query my data from my FutureBuilder->QuerySnapshot so I can use the content in each document for a single purpose inside my App, I was trying to access the data by using:

```
snapshotsub.data[]
```

But It doesn't seem to work. I was getting an Instance of QuerySnapshot.
 This is my FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document(user.uid).collection('buttons').getDocuments(),
            builder: (context, snapshotsub) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return  Loading();
              }

             //int test = snapshotsub.data

              return Scaffold(
```

This is how the complete part of my code looks:

```
return  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder : ((context, snapshot){
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
           return  Loading();
          }

          int cardamount = snapshot.data['btncount'];

          List<bool> cardsValue = [snapshot.data['device1'], snapshot.data['device2'], snapshot.data['device3']];

          return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document(user.uid).collection('buttons').getDocuments(),
            builder: (context, snapshotsub) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return  Loading();
              }



              return Scaffold(
```

I'm using a Future Builder inside a StreamBuilder to getter my sub-collection info.
This is how my sub-collection database looks:
[image: col]

Answer (score 1):

The future builder should look like as below :

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
 future:Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document(user.uid).collection('buttons').getDocuments(),
builder: (context, snapshotsub) {
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return  Loading();
}


// gets the list of documents form data
final documents = snapshotsub.data.documents;

for (var message in documents) {
    final btn1 = message.data['button1'];
    // more data filteration...
}
```

Hope this helps you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I think it didn't work, I get `I/flutter ( 2701): null
I/chatty  ( 2701): uid=10070(npstech.com.homeautomation) Thread-2 identical 1 line
I/flutter ( 2701): null` This as response, and I can't use the variables inside my code

Comment: Regarding your issue you can request support [here](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) and they will be happy to assist you. In addition to that you can post your concern at the [Community section of Flutter](https://flutter.dev/community) as well to get support and advice by community members. Hope this will guide you in the right direction and resolves the issue.